# what is diffrent between [cell addSubview:button] and [cell.contentview addsubview:button]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

i have button in tableviewcell.
what is diffrent between  `[cell addSubview:button]` and `[cell.contentview addsubview:button]` ?
because when i use `[cell addSubview:button]` in tableview , button function work fine but my interface in table view messed up and button go to left cell after i scroll in views and back to tableview.
in other hand  when i use `[cell.contentview addsubview:button]` button function not work and nothing save to myarray.

button code:

```
UIButton *button=(UIButton *) [cell viewWithTag:103];//fav
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unfav.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fav.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
 button.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 50, 50);

button.tag = indexPath.row;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell addSubview:button]; // add the button to the cell
[cell bringSubviewToFront:button];
```

Comment: Obviously the difference is at the view you are adding subviews to.

Answer (score 4):

The `contentView` is the default view for the cell in which all the `subviews` are added.The cell.view is the main view in which `contentView` is itself added and cell.`contentView` covers the whole area of the cell.view. But in your case when you added the button to cell.view.

From apple docs about `ContentView`,

> The content view of a `UITableViewCell` object is the default `SuperView` for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView